# I can't turn hair mask (aplha) on my model invisible

Tags: shaders, transparency, shader-nodes

I'm a total noob with the shaders for starters, and i'm unable to grasp how to make alpha (black part) invisible.

[image]

I downloaded this model to play around and found myself unable to make his hair look normal. I looked around for answers but the common solution to this problem (shader script below) doesn't seem to work for me, at all.
[image]

I'm currently stuck and don't know what to do about it at all.
All help greatly welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like your image has transparency (alpha layer), just a black background. You could simply use it as a mask in the *Alpha* input of the *Principled BSDF* and the color of the beard will be determined by the *Base Color* of the *Principled BSDF*. In Eevee don't forget to choose *Material > Settings > Blend Mode > Alpha Blend* if you want transparency.

[image]

You could also choose this mix (mix a *Transparent* with a *Principled BSDF* in a *Mix Shader* with the *Image Texture* as mask), which should give the same result as above:

[image]

Comment: hello. Your answer was right, and not only that but now I know how to make potential hair in the future, and i'm grateful for your help. As an aditional question, do you think this type of hair will look like that in game engine for example UE4 ? Anyway thanks.

Comment: edit: oh yes of course you'll have the same result in the game engine, I don't know how you must prepare your material though